# Finding a $\gamma$ to define a Kummer extension like $E=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)(X^5-\gamma)$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, elliptic-curves, kummer-theory

**Previous theory:** All the cyclic extensions of order $5$ are $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)(\sqrt[5]{\gamma})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ where $\zeta_5$ is the generator of the group $\left(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\right)^*$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5).$ They are not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ in general, but using Elliptic Curves there is a way to find infinite Kummer extensions Galois over $\mathbb{Q}.$

It does not matter the way is used to find them, the important thing is that I found that for exemple the polynomial $x^{20} - 2x^{19} -
2x^{18} + 18x^{17} - 32x^{16} + 88x^{15} +
58x^{14} - 782x^{13} + 1538x^{12} +
1348x^{11}- 466x^{10 }- 894x^9 +
346x^8 - 114x^7 - 424x^6 - 88x^5 +214x^4 + 54x^3 + 14x^2 + 4x + 1$
defines a Kummer extension $E$ (it is cyclyc of order $5$, thus for the theory it is Kummer and is classificated).

So I want to find $\gamma$ such that $E=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)(X^5-\gamma)$. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

EDIT: As user Johaness Huisman proposed me, this is the polynomial in a quoted form for being used on a mathematical software:

> x^20 - 2*x^19 - 2*x^18 + 18*x^17 - 32*x^16 + 88*x^15 + 58*x^14 -
>                       782*x^13 + 1538*x^12 + 1348*x^11 - 466*x^10 - 894*x^9 + 346*x^8 -
>                       114*x^7 - 424*x^6 - 88*x^5 + 214*x^4 + 54*x^3 + 14*x^2 + 4*x + 1

Comment: Can you give your polynomial also in quoted form so that one can do copy-paste into a symbolic math software package please?

Comment: What does the notation E = etc. mean ?

Comment: A field, I want to express the number field generated by the polynomial showed, in terms like: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)(\sqrt[5]{\gamma})$

Comment: What does this have to do with elliptic curves? Kummer theory (within the context here) doesn't involve elliptic curves...